# Generate boolean expression from FSM state table in python

Tags: python, fsm, truthtable

I have a rather large state machine with the following state table:
[image]

This is already running it through espresso, so the original is quite large. The inputs and transitions are the y's and n's and the outputs are the d's.

I am looking for a tool that can then generate the boolean expressions for each output using sum of products. I have found several tools that can generate a truth table and from there the expression (pyeda,pypi) but so far haven't found something that will work for a 'customized' truth table like I have below. I don't want to fill out the entire truth table because it would be huge and these are all the states and transitions that I care about.

Anybody know a good tool that already exists?